# How to reconstruct an Object from Elastic Search for React Native?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, elasticsearch

So I have an object that looks like:

```
{
  2000 - 2005: { from: 2000, to: 2005, doc_count: 32 }
  2006 - 2010: { from: 2006, to: 2010, doc_count: 77 }
  2011 - 2015: { from: 2011, to: 2015, doc_count: 94 }
  2016 - 2018: { from: 2016, to: 2018, doc_count: 28 }
}
```

But I want it to look more like

```
[{ label: "2016-2018", from: 2016, to: 2018, doc_count: 28} ] (etc)
```

So that I can map over and display the needed values

Figured reconstructing the original object into an array is the direction I should go in.

The issue comes from using an ElasticSearch Keyed response. [Here's the Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation). Take a look ay "Keyed Response". When `Keyed: true` then the response I get is an object but when `Keyed` is not being used, I get an array like I'm trying to create (scroll up in the documentation to see that example)

So do I reconstruct the object or is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to set your key in the 1st object as a label key in your wanted array. Use Object.keys to get the keys, then you can use map to recombine it with the original data

```
const info = Object.keys(yourData).map((label, index) => {...yourData[index], label};
```

note: may not be standarized yet

or

```
const info = Object.keys(yourData).map((label, index) => {
   let datapoint = yourData[index];
   yourData.label = label;
   return yourData;
})
```

There might be a better way to do this through elasticsearch, but unless you have a lot data, this is very easy and quick